# How do I implement a DS1302 real-time clock sensor into the following code?

Tags: arduino, real-time, sensors, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

The following code is code for an automated food delivery system, and this system needs to begin operating at a specific time, 12 pm sharp.
How can I, using Arduino IDE, implement a DS1302 real-time clock sensor into the code that makes it run at 12 pm and repeat every 15 minutes?
Any tips, notes, or help is appreciated :)

The code I used is the following:

```
#define enA 10//Enable1 L298 Pin enA 
#define in1 9 //Motor1  L298 Pin in1 
#define in2 8 //Motor1  L298 Pin in1 
#define in3 7 //Motor2  L298 Pin in1 
#define in4 6 //Motor2  L298 Pin in1 
#define enB 5 //Enable2 L298 Pin enB 

#define L_S A0 //ir sensor Left
#define R_S A1 //ir sensor Right

#define echo A2    //Echo pin
#define trigger A3 //Trigger pin

#define servo A5

int Set=15;
int distance_L, distance_F, distance_R; 

void setup(){ // put your setup code here, to run once

Serial.begin(9600); // start serial communication at 9600bps

pinMode(R_S, INPUT); // declare if sensor as input  
pinMode(L_S, INPUT); // declare ir sensor as input

pinMode(echo, INPUT );// declare ultrasonic sensor Echo pin as input
pinMode(trigger, OUTPUT); // declare ultrasonic sensor Trigger pin as Output  

pinMode(enA, OUTPUT); // declare as output for L298 Pin enA 
pinMode(in1, OUTPUT); // declare as output for L298 Pin in1 
pinMode(in2, OUTPUT); // declare as output for L298 Pin in2 
pinMode(in3, OUTPUT); // declare as output for L298 Pin in3   
pinMode(in4, OUTPUT); // declare as output for L298 Pin in4 
pinMode(enB, OUTPUT); // declare as output for L298 Pin enB 

analogWrite(enA, 200); // Write The Duty Cycle 0 to 255 Enable Pin A for Motor1 Speed 
analogWrite(enB, 200); // Write The Duty Cycle 0 to 255 Enable Pin B for Motor2 Speed 

pinMode(servo, OUTPUT);

 for (int angle = 70; angle <= 140; angle += 5)  {
   servoPulse(servo, angle);  }
 for (int angle = 140; angle >= 0; angle -= 5)  {
   servoPulse(servo, angle);  }

 for (int angle = 0; angle <= 70; angle += 5)  {
   servoPulse(servo, angle);  }

distance_F = Ultrasonic_read();

delay(500);
}


void loop(){  
//==============================================
//     Line Follower and Obstacle Avoiding
//==============================================  

distance_F = Ultrasonic_read();
Serial.print("D F=");Serial.println(distance_F);


//if Right Sensor and Left Sensor are at White color then it will call forword function
 if((digitalRead(R_S) == 0)&&(digitalRead(L_S) == 0)){
  if(distance_F > Set){forword();}
                  else{Check_side();}  
 }  
 
//if Right Sensor is Black and Left Sensor is White then it will call turn Right function
else if((digitalRead(R_S) == 1)&&(digitalRead(L_S) == 0)){turnRight();}  

//if Right Sensor is White and Left Sensor is Black then it will call turn Left function
else if((digitalRead(R_S) == 0)&&(digitalRead(L_S) == 1)){turnLeft();} 
    
delay(10);
}

void servoPulse (int pin, int angle){
int pwm = (angle*11) + 500;      // Convert angle to microseconds
 digitalWrite(pin, HIGH);
 delayMicroseconds(pwm);
 digitalWrite(pin, LOW);
 delay(50); // Refresh cycle of servo
}


//**********************Ultrasonic_read****************************
long Ultrasonic_read(){
  digitalWrite(trigger, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigger, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  long time = pulseIn (echo, HIGH);
  return time / 29 / 2;
}

void compareDistance(){
    if(distance_L > distance_R){
  turnLeft();
  delay(500);
  forword();
  delay(600);
  turnRight();
  delay(500);
  forword();
  delay(600);
  turnRight();
  delay(400);
  }
  else{
  turnRight();
  delay(500);
  forword();
  delay(600);
  turnLeft();
  delay(500);
  forword();
  delay(600);  
  turnLeft();
  delay(400);
  }
}

void Check_side(){
    Stop();
    delay(100);
 for (int angle = 70; angle <= 140; angle += 5)  {
   servoPulse(servo, angle);  }
    delay(300);
    distance_R = Ultrasonic_read();
    Serial.print("D R=");Serial.println(distance_R);
    delay(100);
  for (int angle = 140; angle >= 0; angle -= 5)  {
   servoPulse(servo, angle);  }
    delay(500);
    distance_L = Ultrasonic_read();
    Serial.print("D L=");Serial.println(distance_L);
    delay(100);
 for (int angle = 0; angle <= 70; angle += 5)  {
   servoPulse(servo, angle);  }
    delay(300);
    compareDistance();
}

void forword(){  //forword
digitalWrite(in1, LOW); //Left Motor backword Pin 
digitalWrite(in2, HIGH); //Left Motor forword Pin 
digitalWrite(in3, HIGH); //Right Motor forword Pin 
digitalWrite(in4, LOW); //Right Motor backword Pin 
}

void backword(){ //backword
digitalWrite(in1, HIGH); //Left Motor backword Pin 
digitalWrite(in2, LOW); //Left Motor forword Pin 
digitalWrite(in3, LOW); //Right Motor forword Pin 
digitalWrite(in4, HIGH); //Right Motor backword Pin 
}

void turnRight(){ //turnRight
digitalWrite(in1, LOW); //Left Motor backword Pin 
digitalWrite(in2, HIGH); //Left Motor forword Pin 
digitalWrite(in3, LOW); //Right Motor forword Pin 
digitalWrite(in4, HIGH); //Right Motor backword Pin 
}

void turnLeft(){ //turnLeft
digitalWrite(in1, HIGH); //Left Motor backword Pin 
digitalWrite(in2, LOW); //Left Motor forword Pin 
digitalWrite(in3, HIGH); //Right Motor forword Pin 
digitalWrite(in4, LOW); //Right Motor backword Pin 
}

void Stop(){ //stop
digitalWrite(in1, LOW); //Left Motor backword Pin 
digitalWrite(in2, LOW); //Left Motor forword Pin 
digitalWrite(in3, LOW); //Right Motor forword Pin 
digitalWrite(in4, LOW); //Right Motor backword Pin 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao,
so, if I understand well, You want certain tasks being activated at minute 00, 15, 30 and 45 every hour starting from day 1 at 00:00.

There are several ways to implement it, and also depends on which board You are using.
Unfortunately the DS1302 RTC (real time clock) has no hardware alarm capability (no  output that can trigger, for example, and Arduino microcontroller interrupt).

So You have to implement a software solution.
There are several ways to implement it, some of which can be implemented in all "Arduino" boards, other that are use the specific hardware capabilities of some boards (internal RTC).

The more simple is to set, in the "setup" section of Arduino code, the start day, hour and minute of the first start of your repetitive task, and read periodically day, hour and minute from the RTC via I2C.
When start start day, hour and minute match than run the tasks You need.
In the "loop" periodically reading the actual minute from the RTC You'll have the possibility to start the tasks You want to do at the minute you want (minute 00, 15, 30 and 45).

This rudimental solution is useful only for very simple tasks.

Hereafter You find a better solution that answers your question and gives you more freedom for developing more complex tasks in a simpler way.
These solutions could appear more complex, but in reality are easier to implement even for not very complex tasks and make a better use of the hardware resources of a microcontroller.

Some alternative solutions:

1. Use TimeAlarms library that allows to do tasks at a set time or periodically.
   From the documentation: "... Tasks scheduled at a particular time of day are called Alarms, tasks scheduled after an interval of time has elapsed are called Timers. These tasks can be created to continuously repeat or to occur once only.  ..."

If the your Arduino (or compatible) board microcontroller with Samd architecture (Arduino Zero, Due, Nano 33 IoT, ...), that has an internal RTC, than You can use, for example, also:

2. RTCZero library that allows, from documentation, "RTC peripheral of an Arduino Zero or MKR1000 to program actions related to date and time"

Since You can use the internal RTC, than You don't need the DS1302 RTC, so reducing the hardware parts needed.

The above are only a limited number of the several alternatives that allow to implement a solution to your question.

There is also a hardware alternative: use a different RTC, one with alarm output pin (and calendar), as, for example, the DS332 or DS3231.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).